# SAP UI5 Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am new to SAP Fiori and am trying to use the SAP UI5 application development tools for Eclipse.
I am following the steps mentioned in blogs like
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/11/19/sap-fiori-ui5-application-creation

I have the following versions
Eclipse (version 4.16.0) - Bundled with Spring Tool Suite 4.7.0
UI5 plugin (version 1.71.1) - Downloaded from  https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2019-12

When I configure a simple project and run as Run As > Web App Preview, I do not see any change, even the index.html page does not open up.

Could you advise me if there is any error that I can see?
Looking at this page https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/, it seems that the SAPUI5 plugin has not been made avalable Eclipse Oxygen onwards.

Also, is it a right idea to use Eclipse for developing SAP UI 5 applications? If not Eclipse, which is the better way to go forward?

Thank you,
Prabal Rakshit

Comment: I think the Eclipse Plugin is deprecated/dead. Most are using VSCode in combination with the npm package [ui5-tooling](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/GettingStarted/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Eclipse 2019-12 you can use it for UI5 developments and webide personal edition
or VSCode with npm install.

if you interest in cloud deployments you can go for Business application Studio(BAS)[https://bas-fiori.eu10cf.trial.applicationstudio.cloud.sap/index.html][1] It was SAP recommended.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: October, 2022**

> Because there are more powerful development environments out there that offer integration with SAPUI5 app development (see for example the ui5-ecosystem-showcase), we have decided to retire the SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse. They will no longer be updated after UI5 release 1.71 and won’t support Eclipse versions higher than 2019-12.

If you want to read more about it here is the link: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/11/26/sapui5-tools-for-eclipse-now-is-the-time-to-look-for-alternatives/

### *Installation VS Code and plugins for SAPUI5:*

1. Download and install **VS Code**: https://code.visualstudio.com/download
2. Download and install **NodeJs**: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
   [image]
3. Restart your computer
4. Open VS Code
5. Go to extensions
   [image]
6. Search **SAP Fiori Tools - Extension Pack** this contains all the extensions required
   [image]
7. Then, you can press **ctrl+shift+p** or: [image]
8. Search **Explore and Install Generators:**
   [image]
9. Sometimes it is slow to open, but when it works you need search **SAP** to find the **last available version offer by SAP** and press Install Button (In my case already did it)
   [image]
10. When it is finally installed, you can press again **ctrl+shift+p** and then type **Fiori: Open application generator** anc click the option when it appears:
    [image]
11. Now it is ready to start:
    [image]

I hope that this work for you as works for me

---

**If you really need Eclipse try this: (Not recomended)**
*UI Development Toolkit for HTML5*:

*https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/2019-12*

[image]

Now it works for me:

[image]